# How to enable pmd specific tasks as a separate task and not on the build task

Tags: java, gradle, pmd

I want to run `pmdMain`, `pmdTest` `only` as a custom task (say `./gradlew pmd`) and `not` part of the build task (i.e `./gradlew build`). This is how I am enabling pmdMain right now, but how do I do this for pmdTest as well

```
pmdMain {
    enabled = gradle.startParameter.taskNames.contains('pmdMain')
}
```